# UITableView subview inside UITableViewCell won't display

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableview, where each cell contains another UITableView.  It's basically a list of 2-3 rows, where each row then has a sublist of 2-3 rows inside.

The main ViewController behaves just like any other TableViewController, and inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath, it attempts to add a SubTableViewController.view with a dynamic height.  The SubTableViewController is the second tableview and each has their own Datasource.

The problem I'm running into is the SubTableViewController appears to render properly using the debugger, with the correct data and number of cells, but it simply isn't appearing when rendering. I noticed it has a contentSize height of "0" in its ViewDidAppear, despite having 2+ rows produced with height.  The project uses AutoLayout but the SubTableViewController's frame is set programmatically when added.

Any ideas what I can do to get something to appear here?

Structure of Data (periods are the subTable)

```
[{name:"activity 1",
  periods:[{name:"period1",desc:"desc1"},
           {name:"period2",desc:"desc2"},
           {name:"period3",desc:"desc3"}
          ]
 },
 {name:"activity 2",
  periods:[{name:"period1",desc:"desc1"},
           {name:"period2",desc:"desc2"},
           {name:"period3",desc:"desc3"}
          ]
 }]
```

**ViewController**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_data count];
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UIView *subTableView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];

    return imageView.frame.size.height + subTableView.frame.size.height + 20;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"tableViewCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    ActivityModel *model = _data[indexPath.row];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    nameLabel.text = model.name;

    UIView *internalView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:10];

    SubTableViewController *subTableViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SubTableViewController"];
    subTableViewController.activityModel = model;
    subTableViewController.view.tag = 3;
    subTableViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                                                   60,
                                         internalView.frame.size.width,                                        
                       subTableViewController.view.frame.size.height);
    [internalView addSubview:subTableViewController.view];
    [internalView bringSubviewToFront:subTableViewController.view];
    [subTableViewController.tableView reloadData];


    return cell;
}
```

**SubTableViewController**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


    int height = 0;
    for (int section = 0; section < [self numberOfSectionsInTableView:_tableView]; section++){
        for(int row = 0; row < [self tableView:_tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section]; row++){
            height += [self tableView:_tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row inSection:section]];
        }
    }

    CGRect tableFrame = self.tableView.frame;
    tableFrame.size.height = height;
    self.tableView.frame = tableFrame;

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.size.height = height;
    self.view.frame = viewFrame;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:_tableView];

    // [self.tableView layoutIfNeeded];
    // [self.tableView setNeedsDisplay];
    // [self.tableView reloadData];
    // _tableView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(600, 52);

    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

    self.tableView.hidden = NO;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_activityModel.periods count];
}
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    float textViewHeight = [textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;

    return nameLabel.frame.size.height + textViewHeight + 20;

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"tableViewCell"];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    PeriodModel *model = _activityModel.periods[indexPath.row];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *durationLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    UITextView *textView = (UITextView*)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    nameLabel.text = model.name;
    durationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d minutes", (int)(model.durationSeconds/60)];

    textView.text = model.description;

    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0;
    textView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    CGRect frame = textView.frame;
    frame.size.height = [textView.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width, MAXFLOAT) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    textView.frame = frame;

    return cell;
}
```

Simulator Image.  The title is the outer UITableCell, and below it in red is the added SubTableViewController.view.  The UITableView should cover the red, but is not appearing at all here.  It is not hidden, underneath, etc.

[image]

Comment: Is there really a good reason for this complex setup? Couldn't you simply use sections and rows for the two levels?

Comment: Note that you're not only using a table view embedded into another one, you're actually using a table view controller. But even though you add its view to the cell, you don't do any other part of the setup involved for child view controllers. So none of the usual view controller methods (loadView, viewDidLoad, viewWill/DidAppear, etc.) will be called, which also involves no setting up of the delegate and datasource...

Comment: I'm working from designs, where I have a nested hierarchy. I could really force the top header part into a custom Section header view, but it really needs to be fixed with the content, not hugging the top as it scrolls like section headers do.  It would also be difficult to flatten the data and still make it appear grouped.    I added the datasource to the desc above to illustrate.

Comment: The viewController and SubTableViewController are both created in the storyboard.  Their delegates/datasources are set.  The sub's viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear do get called.

Comment: You have a two-level hierarchy. That's sections and rows. If you want the header of each section to not hug the top, simply make it the first row of each section instead (with a different cell type). Not sure I understand "It would also be difficult to flatten the data and still make it appear grouped."

Comment: `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` are possibly called when you call `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`. But your view controller is still not in the hierarchy, and you probably don't have any strong references to it, so it's probably dropped as soon as you exit `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, so you end up with no delegate or data source at that point. It's really a recipe for disaster, not to mention the interactions between embedded scroll views, and more. Switch to sections and rows. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: The short answer is "Don't do that." You are building a Frankenstein's monster of a UI. I agree with the other posters that some variant of a sectioned table view is a much better way to go.

Comment: The answer is below, but for the record  "[self addChildViewController:subTableViewController]" got the subtable to appear.  However trying to calculate its height, and the parent cell's height was proving to be tedious, and not worth the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put a table view inside your cells.

There is little benefit to doing this for your described use. Use sections and rows. Each section would be your current cell. And each row in that section would be a row from your current embedded table view.

Further, if your internal table views had differing sizes you would be needing to calculate all of the internal cell heights for each external cell. That is exactly what happens with sections and rows, but you as the developer only need to worry about the rows and `UITableView` will handle the section sizing.

Comment: I would like this if the table section headers did not stick to the top (float) with scrolling.  That won't fly with my project designer for the targeted behavior.  The rest I could probably improvise somehow with a sectionHeader and footer.

Comment: Quick solution to that: make headers 0 height (or no title at least) and make the first row of each section your new "header". Just offsets your indexes by 1. Grouped design also maybe?

Comment: I ended up using the flat table of sections.  No section headers. Row count of internalData+1, and uses two tableViewCell layouts, the first for the "header" and the other for the repeating content.   Works well enough.  No floating section headers either.